# How to remove tool tip icon in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.2, shipping-address

I wish to remove tooltip icon in checkout page.

1) Wish to remove near email and phone number

Comment: Check my answer it will help you.

Comment: Let me know if still, you have face issue, or if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tickmark for right ansewer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it by this way.

> app/code/Company/Checkout/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="custom-checkout-process" type="Company\Checkout\Plugin\LayoutProcessorPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Company/Checkout/Plugin/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Checkout\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param $jsLayout
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        //Remove telephone tooltip
        unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['config']['tooltip']);

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Rund the command.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: @Sri always happy to help!

Comment: How to add tool tip for discount section on magento2 checkout page? please advise